# How do I reorder search results with Semantic UI's local search?

Tags: typeahead, semantic-ui

I have a local search box using Semantic 2.1 with an array of hashes.

```
[{ title: 'Andorra' , rank: 1 } , { title: 'United Arab Emirates', rank: 2 } , { title: 'Afghanistan' , rank: 3 } , { title: 'Antigua' , rank: 4 } ,...]
```

I would like the search results to be ordered in the order I have the hashes in the array.
For example, searching the countries with the search string `Ar`, right now I get

```
Armenia
Argentina
Aruba
Andorra
United Arab Emirates
American Samoa
Austria
```

But I would like to display

```
United Arab Emirates
Armenia
Argentina
...
```

Is there a way to do to do that without rewriting the source?

Here's the demo fiddle I setup: http://jsfiddle.net/zestly/ckxpvgm7/1/

As a bonus question, can anyone explain why American Samoa gets returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only method I know is to override the results HTML creation for the search function using something like this:

```
$.fn.search.settings.templates = {
  standard: function(response) {
   // Your own sorting logic here
   var sortedResults = response.results.sort(function(a, b) {
       if (a.title === 'United Arab Emirates' || b.title === 'United Arab Emirates')
           return 1;
       else if (a.rank > b.rank)
           return 1;
       else if (a.rank < b.rank)
           return -1;
       else
           return 0;
   });

   // Create the DOM as as it normally should be
   return $.map(sortedResults, function(item) {
     return $('<div>').append($('<a>').addClass('result').append(
       $('<div>').addClass('content').append(
         $('<div>').addClass('title').text(item.title)
       )
     )).html();
   });
  }
};
```

This is the last time you have access to the results array before it is drawn onto the results container. You can re-arrange it using your own sorting logic and then build up a results DOM which matches what would normally be returned anyway.

Comment: Thanks. This works. Here's a fiddle with your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ckxpvgm7/5/

I wish this was part of the API.